# AFNetworkActivityManager for AlamoFire?

Tags: afnetworking-2, alamofire

`AFNetworking` allows one to do:

```
[[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];
```

But I have not figured out how to do this with the `Swift` `AlamoFire` equivalent. I've searched the source for some of the same terms, but don't see anything yet.

(I'm learning Swift, so be gentle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assessment is correct @travis. There is currently no support for such an activity indicator in the latest version of Alamofire. If you need this functionality, you'll have to build it out on your own at the moment. With that said, I know the project is always accepting PRs having submitted many myself.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. I've never done a pull request before. I assume I'd have to figure out how to use AF from a git repository rather than the nice and easy cocoapod.